# PHP database image not loading from database

Tags: php, sql, database

First line of code.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`,
               `username`,
               `password`,
               `firstname`,
               `lastname`,
               `activated`,
               `email`,
               `randSalt`,
               `photo`
          FROM `TEST`
         WHERE username = '$usname'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$uid = $row[0];
$dbUsname = $row[1];
$dbPassword = $row[2];
// Check if the username and the password they entered was correct
if ($usname == $dbUsname && $paswd == $dbPassword) {
    // Set session 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $usname;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $uid;
    $photo = $row[0];
    // Now direct to users feed
    header("Location: user.php");
```

On my other code `user.php` I have a line code that is:

```
<img class="pp" src="<?php echo $photo;?>"/>
```

But it does not display an image!

Comment: probably because photo is not $row[0] but $row[8].

Comment: it was originally was $row[8] but it still didn`t work!

Comment: `$photo` is a variable on THIS page, and since you are not saving it as a Session value, AND you are going to `user.php`, `$photo` is not set on `user.php`

Comment: What should i then do to fix this problem?

Comment: You could save it as a Session variable -> `$_SESSION['photo'] = $row[8];`. Then in `user.php` -> `<?php start_session(); $photo = $_SESSION['photo']; ?> <img class="pp" src="<?php echo $photo;?>"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to change line

```
$photo = $row[8];
```

You should generate html like this one:

```
<img class="pp"                
       src='data:image/jpeg;base64, LzlqLzRBQ...<!-- base64 data -->' />
```

If you aren't storing your data already base64 encoded in database, then you might need to use PHP function [base64_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you store only a path to the photo in your database, try this:

```
$_SESSION['photo'] = $row[8];
```

And in user.php:

```
<img class="pp" src="<?php echo $_SESSION['photo']; ?>"/>
```

This is the easyest but not the best solution of your problem. The better way is in this situation, if you make a query in the user page, which is get the user datas, depens on the SESSION user ID is isset and valid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are storing the image itself in the database (rather than the path to the image), you will need to include a base64 image inline in the HTML. Your output should be this:

```
<img class="pp" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $photo; ?>"/>
```

This assumes that your images are JPEGs. They they are not, change `image/jpeg` to `image/png` or whatever image format you're using.

You need to change the `$photo` assignment to:

```
$photo = $row[8];
```

Using `$row[0]` will assign the ID to `$photo` rather than what is stored in the photo column.

If your images are **not** stored base64 encoded you will need to encode them before you output them. In this case when you assign the photo variable do this instead:

```
$photo = base64_encode($row[8]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `user.php`

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { session_start(); }

$photo = '/img/default.png'; // A default photo if none is provided

$uid = false;
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $uid = filter_var($_SESSION['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); 
}

if($uid !== false) {
    // User ID is set in session variable and was integer

    $sql = "SELECT `photo` FROM `TEST` WHERE `id`=" . $uid . " LIMIT 1;";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    if($query) {
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
            if(trim($row[0] . '') != '') {
                // if img is not stored as base64, then make sure field type is blob
                $photo = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($row[0]);

                // if img is stored as base64, then uncomment the following line and comment above line
                // $photo = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($row[0]);
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($query);
    }
    mysqli_close($dbCon);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $photo; ?>" />
```

Basically, it does the following :

- Checks if session exists and starts it
- Checks and sanitizes `$_SESSION['id']` as an integer (assumes your `id` field is autonumber integer)
- Opens the database connection and uses the photo data associated with the `id` stored in `$_SESSION`
- If no image found, uses '/img/default.png' (configurable) as the default.
- Cleans up database connection and frees memory from results found.

**There are two options inside:**
- The first method assumes you are storing the image as a BINARY LARGE OBJECT (aka, BLOB), and does not account for VERY LARGE images which you will need to stream from the database.
- The second method (commented out), assumes you are `base64_encode`ing the image before storing it.

All cases, assume the field is large enough to store the image completely.

---

Footnote:  Remove `$photo = $row[0];` from the first block you posted as it does nothing. In no way will that line of code ever reach `user.php` the way it is written.

Comment: What qualifies for "VERY LARGE"? According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) large (i.e. 4kb) is enough motivation for streaming.

Comment: Generally, you can base64_encode images up to around 15-20kb without any issue... sometimes larger.  100kb+ definitely exceeds what can be displayed in most browsers using `base64`.